# I keep getting the error 'The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid. None of the options match with.. You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop

Tags: material-ui

My AutoComplete works fine when I use it for the first time. However, when I load the options and the selected value after relaunching the page with the data from the database, I get this warning:

'The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid. None of the options match with..  You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop'

I have confirmed that the value provided matches with the options. When I click to see the options, I can see it there as well. Is the warning because of the strict equality check? Do I need to use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop?

Comment: Did u manage to find the answer?

Comment: Yes, using the isOptionEqualToValue prop is what solved my issue.